# Remove TR with certain content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with the following structure:

```
| abc|1 | def | ghi |
| erg|1 | asd | dfg |
| sdf|2 | ghj | erd |
| tsd|2 | sdf | hgj |
```

I now want to hide all `tr` where the suffix `|2` can be found in the first `td`. So the result should be:

```
| abc|1 | def | ghi |
| erg|1 | asd | dfg |
```

This is my approach:

```js
$('table tr').each(function() {
  $(this).find("\\|2").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|1</td>
    <td>sdf</td>
    <td>hfgh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|1</td>
    <td>3sf</td>
    <td>gdfg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|1</td>
    <td>sdf</td>
    <td>jfhj</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|2</td>
    <td>sdf</td>
    <td>hfgh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|2</td>
    <td>3sf</td>
    <td>gdfg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|2</td>
    <td>sdf</td>
    <td>jfhj</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsmtstxo/1/).

But that doesn't produce any result.

Comment: find looks for a selector and that is not a selector, it does not look at text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

```js
$('table tr:contains(|2)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|1</td>
    <td>sdf</td>
    <td>hfgh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|1</td>
    <td>3sf</td>
    <td>gdfg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|1</td>
    <td>sdf</td>
    <td>jfhj</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|2</td>
    <td>sdf</td>
    <td>hfgh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|2</td>
    <td>3sf</td>
    <td>gdfg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla|2</td>
    <td>sdf</td>
    <td>jfhj</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `.find()` works. Try this instead:

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
  if ($(this).children('td').eq(0).text().match("\\|2")) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://%20jsfiddle.net/0839n7sq)

Comment: That is not going to match the text since that is not a regular expression in the match()

Comment: Oh really? https://jsfiddle.net/0839n7sq/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.endsWith`

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.find('td').eq(0).text().endsWith("|2")) {
        $this.hide();
    }
});
```

what actually happening here is we are finding whether the content of first column of every row endsWith `|2`

Answer (score 0):

You have to find td which [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) "|2":-

```
$(this).find('td:contains("|2")').parent('tr').hide();
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsmtstxo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following code

```
$('tr:contains(|2)').hide();
```

Update:

To restrict to check in first td only,

```
$('tr td:first-child:contains(|2)').parent('tr').hide();
```